# How to Export database data table to Excel Sheet in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I have a requirement that , i have a table of 400 columns.

Here i need to Export this table to Excel sheet.

And i need to upload to Open Office Sheet. I do not have MS-office.

This is in ASP.NET and C#.NET

I am new to this concept.

So please help me to solve this.

And friends there is a problem , i have 400 columns , which is not possible to insert into Open Office Excel , i need to insert other columns into new sheet

Thank You All!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelGenerator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can look at using OleDB to do this

[Reading and Writing Excel Spreadsheets Using ADO.NET](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx)

I've used this method a number of times and found it to be quick and effective.

3rd Alternative, if it doesn't have to be a true xls/xlsx file and you want lots of control over what the final output looks like, try Microsoft's Spreadsheet XML.

[XML Spreadsheet Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(office.10).aspx)

Again, I've used this method to great effect

Answer (score 0):

You can read from one source and update to another using DataSet, with 2 distinct tOleDb connections.

Here's some code that does that.

[CopyData-SqlToExcel-TwoOledbConnections.cs](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=MSOffice&file=CopyData-SqlToExcel-TwoOledbConnections.cs)